# Cocoa - NSEvent Respond to the SHIFT key?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsevent

I was wondering if NSEvent responds to the "Shift" key on the keyboard. I am logging the keyCodes when debugging my app and I don't get a keyCode value for the shift key.

Thanks,

Kevin

EDIT: This is the code I am using from a user response.

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event
{   

    if ([event modifierFlags] == NSShiftKeyMask) {
        NSLog(@"Shift key pressed");
    }
}
```

The Shift key is still not being recognized...

Comment: This code seems to work only when you press shift a a modifier to _another_ key (e.g., shift + A). It is not triggered when you press the shift key all by itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at the [`flagsChanged:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsresponder/1527647-flagschanged) method of `NSResponder`.

Something like this:

```
- (void) flagsChanged:(NSEvent *) event {
    if ([event modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Would the anonymous -1 please explain?

Comment: T'would be nice if you posted the code that fixed your issue. :)

Comment: something like `- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)event { if ([event modifierFlags] && NSShiftKeyMask == NSShiftKeyMask) { /*do something*/} }` (untested)

Comment: @Richard, this works if you use a bitwise operator. In you comment, change the boolean && to a single &.

Comment: @boyfarrell yep, that's a typo on my part.  Comment is too old to edit, though.

Answer (score 9):

Your code sample isn't working because `-modifierFlags` is a bitmask and so testing whether the mask is equal to `NSShiftKeyMask` won't work. You need to use the bitwise `AND` operator to test if the flag is set:

```
if ([event modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask) {
    NSLog(@"Shift key pressed");
}
```

Also as an aside if you want to store this result in a `BOOL` you need to check that it is not equal to 0, such as:

```
BOOL shiftKeyPressed = ([event modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask) != 0;
```

If you leave it out then the `BOOL` will evaluate to `NO` (unless the value you pull out of the bitmask is 1 which is defined as `YES`; for `-modifierFlags` this won't happen as the masks start at `1 << 16`).

Answer (score 3):

Use this to capture changed flags :

```
- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)event
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution to detecting modifier key changes:

```
- (void)keyboard:(AMKeyboardView *)keyboard flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)event {
    if ((event.modifierFlags & NSShiftKeyMask) && !lastShiftState) {
        lastShiftState = true;
        //Shift pressed - do something
    }
    else if (!(event.modifierFlags & NSShiftKeyMask) && lastShiftState) {
        lastShiftState = false;
        //Shift released - do something
    }

    else if ((event.modifierFlags & NSFunctionKeyMask) && !lastFnState) {
        lastFnState = true;
        //Fn pressed - do something
    }
    else if (!(event.modifierFlags & NSFunctionKeyMask) && lastFnState) {
        lastFnState = false;
        //Fn released - do something
    }

    else if ((event.modifierFlags & NSControlKeyMask) && !lastControlState) {
        lastControlState = true;
        //Control pressed - do something
    }
    else if (!(event.modifierFlags & NSControlKeyMask) && lastControlState) {
        lastControlState = false;
        //Control released - do something
    }


    else if ((event.modifierFlags & NSAlternateKeyMask) && !lastOptionState) {
        lastOptionState = true;
        //Option pressed - do something
    }
    else if (!(event.modifierFlags & NSAlternateKeyMask) && lastOptionState) {
        lastOptionState = false;
        //Option released - do something
    }

    else if ((event.modifierFlags & NSCommandKeyMask) && !lastCommandState) {
        lastCommandState = true;
        //Command pressed - do something
    }
    else if (!(event.modifierFlags & NSCommandKeyMask) && lastCommandState) {
        lastCommandState = false;
        //Command released - do something
    }

    else NSLog(@"Other");
}
```

It requires 4 instance variables to store previous states, but can detect the press and release of every modifier key.

Comment: Something like this is unfortunately necessary as, when a modifier key is released, it doesn't issue it's flag, so in order to track when each modifier is released you need to check both if a flag changes and if a flag was previously set.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's possible to desynchronize your variables from reality. For example, when focus is lost on your app whilst a modifier was held down, then release while your app isn't the foreground window. It'd be better to use flagsChanged to call a method which directly samples the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

The Shift key doesn't have a key code, since it's a key modifier.  When you get a key event, the presence of the Shift key will be in the `modifierFlags` field.

Comment: The Shift key still doesn't respond in the keyDown method in my class.