# keyDown event not working for shift key and only shift key

Tags: swift, macos

I am making this app, and I want to detect whether a shift key is being detected. My code is as follows:

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode == Keycode.shift || event.keyCode == Keycode.shift){
        //do whatever when the shift key is pressed
        print("shift key is being pressed.")
    }
}
```

The struct is from this GitHub: [github link here](https://gist.github.com/swillits/df648e87016772c7f7e5dbed2b345066)

I tried changing the key code to keyCode.q, and it works fine when q is pressed. It seems as if only the shift key isn't working, and I am not sure why. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Note: When I type regularly, I know my shift key works.

Comment: Shift is a key modifier. Try the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640696/cocoa-nsevent-respond-to-the-shift-key

Comment: I don't know any objective-c which is why I asked here. Like I couldn't understand objective c even if my life depended on it. :(

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`NSResponder.flagsChanged(with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1527647-flagschanged)

Comment: But once I press shift it is permanent. How would I change this so when shift is pressed, the do whatever is done, but when not, whatever happened is undone?

Comment: @JerryQian You inspect the `NSEvent.type` value to see if it's `.keyDown` or `.keyUp`.